# Google Geocode API: 'administrative_area:in|country:US' Not Found

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api, geocode

Why does this find Indiana:
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=administrative_area:in

But this does not?
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=administrative_area:in|country:US

Answer (score 1):

It works fine if you use `ind` instead of a `in`.

https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:US|administrative_area:ind&key=

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Indiana",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Indiana, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 41.761368,
                  "lng" : -84.784662
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.7717419,
                  "lng" : -88.097892
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.2671941,
               "lng" : -86.1349019
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 41.761368,
                  "lng" : -84.784662
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.7717419,
                  "lng" : -88.097892
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJHRv42bxQa4gRcuwyy84vEH4",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
```

Comment: According to the documentation separator in address components must be `|`. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering

Comment: Mississippi does not work that way: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=administrative_area:ms&country:US&key=mykey. You have to to it this way: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=administrative_area:ms|country:US&key=mykey

Comment: @delvin-carnate - Thanks but I need this to work with a 2 character state abbreviation and I need it to work for all US states.    "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=administrative_area:<StateAbbrev>|country:US" works for every state but Indiana.

Comment: @rwsimmo : not sure what you're looking for here then?  The two state syntax doesn't work in the case of Indiana, but `ind` does work.  Maybe file a report with Google?

Comment: @delvin-carnate - It is my understanding that Google uses stackoverflow as the community support forum for the api.  So, I am hoping someone from Google sees this.

Comment: See also https://issuetracker.google.com/112513721 ─ the issue tracker is the preferred place to report bugs and file feature requests.